# when malloc'ing struct pointers, do their fixed size variables go to stack?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I create 100000 of such structs, by malloc'ing pointers to them.

```
test_struct test {
    char value[100];
}
```

Does it mean that all char[100] variables (100 * 100000 ~ 10mb) will go to stack memory, exceeding it and causing my program to crash?

Comment: how did you `malloc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

When you allocate a struct on the heap, all of its members go on the heap as well.